# What is the purpose slack field in/proc/pid/status in uclinux

Tags: linux-kernel, mmu, uclinux, linux

Look at the process'status file inside the /proc/pid/status file. Have found below details.

```
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   182
Pid:    182
PPid:   1
TracerPid:      0
Uid:    0       0       0       0
Gid:    0       0       0       0
FDSize: 32
Groups:
Mem:     2206024 bytes
**Slack:    710076 bytes**  << what is the slack or is it stack"
Shared:        0 bytes
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000000001a04
SigCgt: 0000000000016443
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 00000000fffffeff
CapEff: 00000000fffffeff
```

Could some one please look and explain what is the purpose of slack field in status file. is it mistake of the kernel , it must be stack or something else.

One more question when we do any operation on the process Mem Size and slack get increase always , Just wanted to know why memory usage is always increasing. 
Adding more info: like uclinux we have flat memory architecture. 
Would the above reason is for memory size of the processes is keep increasing.

Please suggest your inputs.

Question : or slack  must be stack >> but by mistake code is writing slack. ??
??

Thanks
Karnveer Singh

Comment: Which kernel version are you running ?  - that output is unlike anything on recent normal kernels

Comment: Hi ,Please find the kernel version as below uClinux release 2.4.31-uc0. Thank You

Comment: I am using 2.4.31 . what do you mean by recent normal kernel?? are you including other readhat, suse , ubuntu or etc.

Comment: yes - a 2.4.31 kernel is about 14 years old and very outdated  and the source code for the original 2.4.31 kernel does not produce output like that. However you seem to be running the ucCinuxversion of linux - which is very different from "normal" linux - and I can't find the source code for that to see what it's doing - the uclinux page seems to have been dead for a year or two.